# difference between might and would in the past

Tags: grammar

However drunk he might come home she would always please him / however drunk he would come home she would always please him.
Could a native speaker please tell the nuance I can't hear between might and would in the context. Both denote a habitual action in the past . But what's the difference. Thanks .

Comment: Neither of those is really an idimatic way of saying what you want. The sentence "he would come home drunk" is idiomatic as is "he would come home very drunk" but the use of 'however drunk he might come home' is not what a native speaker would say. What we would say would be 'However drunk he might be _when_ he came home". Don't ask me why, it's just the normal usage.

Comment: However drunk *he might have been* when he came home,

Answer (score 1):

***might*** does not really denote habitual action in the past, although in this phrase the meaning of habit touches it because of the second 'would' ('she would always please him').

I would rather connect ***might*** with ***However*** as they occur in structures like:

> However this might affect her family, she will still have to leave.

***Might*** is rather related to the idea of possibility or eventuality, and that in the past, as well. So your first version of the sentence looks like a habitual possibility in the past, if that makes sense, and it is habitual because of the context, not necessarily because of ***might***. I understand something like:

> However drunk it would be possible for him to come home, she would always please him.

As for ***would*** in your second version of the sentence, I do not think there is any ambiguity there.

Answer (score 0):

Although the grammar here is a bit odd, the difference in nuance between **might** and **would** in this type of conditional is that **would** generally refers to events that already happened, while **might** may also include hypothetical events.

In your example sentence, it's possible that he hasn't ever came home drunk yet, but using the *might* sentence can still make sense if you wanted to say that "even if he does come home drunk, she would still please him".

Using *would* seems to have a stronger implication of it actually have happened before.